# How to use Chessboard.js with Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, chessboard.js

I've been looking a bit at chessboardjs (https://chessboardjs.com/) as a way to get some practice with some React coding. However, I haven't been able to get the simple example of just showing the board in my app working. the documentation says to use `<div id="board" style={{width: 400}}/>` in the HTML, and `var board = ChessBoard('board', 'start');` to get startet. However, `ChessBoard('board', 'start');` gives me an "object not a function" compilation error. I've tried fiddling a lot of different things (such as adding the anonymous function with the jquery tag), but I seem to be doing something wrong. I hope someone can spot it.

My React app (using typescript) has the standard App component, which just has a ChessComponent, which looks the following way:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {ChessBoard} from 'chessboardjs';
import * as $ from 'jquery';

class ChessComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props:any) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        $(function() {
            var board = ChessBoard('board', 'start');
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="board" style={{width: 400}}/>
        )
    }
}

export default ChessComponent
```

and my package.json looks like this:

```
  {
    "name": "chess-app",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
      "chess": "^0.4.1",
      "chessboardjs": "0.0.1",
      "jquery": "^3.4.0",
      "react": "^16.5.2",
      "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.4",
      "react-dom": "^16.5.2",
      "react-scripts-ts": "3.1.0",
      "tslint": "^5.11.0",
      "tslint-react": "^3.6.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
      "start": "react-scripts-ts start --noUnusedParameters=false",
      "build": "react-scripts-ts build",
      "test": "react-scripts-ts test --env=jsdom",
      "eject": "react-scripts-ts eject"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "@types/chessboardjs": "^0.3.1",
      "@types/jest": "^23.3.2",
      "@types/jquery": "^3.3.29",
      "@types/node": "^10.11.3",
      "@types/react": "^16.4.14",
      "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.8",
      "typescript": "^3.1.1"
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case anyone else out there is struggling with a similar issue, I thought I would come back to this and answer my own question.

One trick is to add the necessary scripts to index.html:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@chrisoakman/chessboardjs@1.0.0/dist/chessboard-1.0.0.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-8Vi8VHwn3vjQ9eUHUxex3JSN/NFqUg3QbPyX8kWyb93+8AC/pPWTzj+nHtbC5bxD"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://unpkg.com/@chrisoakman/chessboardjs@1.0.0/dist/chessboard-1.0.0.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-q94+BZtLrkL1/ohfjR8c6L+A6qzNH9R2hBLwyoAfu3i/WCvQjzL2RQJ3uNHDISdU"
      crossorigin="anonymous">
```

That way, both jquery and the chessboardjs functionality are available on the window object. now you can call window.Chessboard to make the board (with a bit of setup).

A quick-n-dirty setup of chessboardjs using reactjs-typescript could look like this:

```js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

// This is a bit of a hack to declare jquery on the window object. It also makes it possible to call window.chessBoard further below
declare var window : any; 
window.$ = window.jQuery = $;

export default class App extends React.Component {
  
  // Please disregard the massive overuse of the any type here
  private boardRef: any;
  private chessBoard: any;
  private boardId: string;
  private defaultConfig: any;

  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.boardRef = React.createRef();
    this.boardId = "board1";
    const themePath = process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/assets/img/chesspieces/wikipedia/{piece}.png'

    this.defaultConfig = {
      appearSpeed: 25,
      draggable: true,
      dropOffBoard: 'snapback',
      moveSpeed: 25,
      orientation: 'white',
      position: 'start',
      showErrors: 'console',
      showNotation: true,
      snapSpeed: 25,
      snapbackSpeed: 50,
      pieceTheme: themePath,
      sparePieces: false,
      trashSpeed: 25,
    };
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    if (window && !window.ChessBoard) return
    if (window && !window.$) return

    this.chessBoard = window.ChessBoard(this.boardId, this.defaultConfig);
  }
  
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.chessBoard.destroy();
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div id={this.boardId} style={{width: "400px"}} ref={this.boardRef}></div>
      </div>
      ); 
    } 
  }
```

However, if you are looking at using Chessboard.js with React I suggest having a look at Simon Ansells React-ChessboardJs-Wrapper: https://github.com/ginger-gm/react-chessboardjs-wrapper

This also makes it easy to add promotion-dialogues to your board.

If you are sitting in a similar pickle with integrating React with other libraries, I also recommend reading their doc on the subject, which I somehow originally missed:

- https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html
- https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Answer (score 2):

If you want to build a chessboard with reactjs I would say [chessboardjsx](https://chessboardjsx.com/) is the way to go . It provide you a Chessboard Component where you can pass different props to customize the board. Below is a sample start position:

```
<Chessboard position="start"/>
```

[image]