# Using jQuery-dependant libraries in ReactJs?

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I am fiddling a bit with ReactJS in my spare time, and a while back I ran into the issue of trying to use a jquery-dependent library in my react application, which let me to ask this question: [How to use Chessboard.js with Reactjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55782304/how-to-use-chessboard-js-with-reactjs)
(admittedly a pretty specific question for a library such as chessboardjs).

As I was just revisiting my old problem (still to no avail so far), I realized there seems to be an architectural issue here. A lot of libraries were built using jQuery, so how does one integrate these libraries into ReactJS applications?

I am entirely aware that ReactJS and jQuery do not fit well together, as they are two different ways of manipulating the DOM, but surely there's a way to take a jQuery-dependent library and integrate it into your application without having to hack around in the source code of the library?

Comment: See https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html. And looks like someone attempted this https://github.com/ginger-gm/react-chessboardjs-wrapper.

Comment: Yeah I was looking a bit at the “integrating with other libraries” page, but I couldn’t quite figure out how to transfer that to my specific use-case. I’ll have a look at the github repo though. Thanks :)